# How can I optimize a database query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am making an application that will select components for a computer for a certain amount.

[ER-diagramm:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PElku.jpg)

I make the following request:

```
SELECT computercases.name, datastorage.name, motherboards.name, powersupply.name, processors.name, ram_memory.name,
    (computercases.price + motherboards.price + graphicscards.price + processors.price + ram_memory.price + 
    datastorage.price + powersupply.price) AS ЦЕНА
    FROM computercases
    JOIN computercasesmotherboards ON computercases.id = computercasesmotherboards.computercasesid
    JOIN motherboards ON computercasesmotherboards.motherboardsid = motherboards.id
    JOIN graphicscardsmotherboards ON motherboards.id = graphicscardsmotherboards.motherboardsid
    JOIN graphicscards ON graphicscardsmotherboards.graphicscardsid = graphicscards.id
    JOIN processorsmotherboards ON motherboards.id = processorsmotherboards.motherboardsid
    JOIN processors ON processorsmotherboards.processorsid = processors.id
    JOIN ram_memorymotherboards ON motherboards.id = ram_memorymotherboards.motherboardsid
    JOIN ram_memory ON ram_memorymotherboards.ram_memoryid = ram_memory.id
    JOIN powersupply ON powersupply.power >= graphicscards.powerconsumption
    CROSS JOIN datastorage
    WHERE (computercases.price + motherboards.price + graphicscards.price +
        processors.price + ram_memory.price + datastorage.price + powersupply.price) >= my_price-1000 and
        (computercases.price + motherboards.price + graphicscards.price +
        processors.price + ram_memory.price + datastorage.price + powersupply.price) <= my_price+1000;
```

But since there is a lot of data in the database, the query is executed for a very long time.

I tried create index:

```
CREATE INDEX CPrice ON computercases(price);
CREATE INDEX DPrice ON datastorage(price);
CREATE INDEX GPrice ON graphicscards(price);
CREATE INDEX MPrice ON motherboards(price);
CREATE INDEX PPrice ON powersupply(price);
CREATE INDEX PrPrice ON processors(price);
CREATE INDEX RPrice ON ram_memory(price);
CREATE INDEX GIndex ON graphicscards(powerconsumption);
CREATE INDEX PIndex ON powersupply(power);
```

But unsuccessfully, the request is executed for a very long time. Maybe I can use LIMIT or something else to optimize the query.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try first to see the query plan of your SQL?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html - that could help a bit. It shows you the number of index scans, the duration of every subquery and gives a lot of insights about the query execution.

Also try `ANALYZE` to actually run the query if you have test env to see how it performs on the real table. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE

Generally speaking your query looks super cumbersome, maybe it makes sense to use materialized views https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html or review the end column set that you would need to reduce amount of data returned

Answer (score 0):

I think, firs try create indexes for JOIN operations. For example

graphicscardsmotherboards(motherboardsid,graphicscardsid)
and
computercasesmotherboards(computerCasesId,motherboardsid)

and so on.

Where clause in your case always need full scan. Optimization for this part of query quite impossible.
Indexes on `Price` are useless.

This `CROSS JOIN datastorage` - it is unclear what there wanted. In this form - very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your query you will have to follow the following step and they include:

1. Indexing:
   Ensure that all the columns that are involved in JOIN conditions and WHERE
   clauses are indexed. In your case, make sure you have indexes on columns
   used in JOIN conditions and the price calculations.
2. Analyze execution plan:
   use the EXPLAIN statement to be able to analyze the query execution plan .
   This will help you to identify which parts of the query are causing
   performance issues.Also review the output to see if the database is using
   the created indexes and where is the most time consuming operation
   occuring.
3. Partitioning:
   Depending on the size of your tables, consider partitioning them.
   Partitioning can improve query performance by allowing the database to scan
   only the relevant partitions.